# Is it possible to package air runtime into my app

Tags: flash, air

Recently I have a task that should write an HTML application and run it in a flash player, the first thought in my mind is **Adobe Air**, but a further requirement is that I should deploy only one .swf file, so I have to figure out an approach.

So is it possible that I could package the entire air runtime into my app so with only a double click my air application can run in a PC without air pre-installed, or is there any other way that can embed an HTML page in a .swf file and run it with flash player.

Thanks

Comment: without air preinstalled it cannot work. do you really need air ? you can send a swf as well if you do not need disk access...

Comment: yes, I may not need air, but air is my currently only known solution, my destination is to embed an HTML file into my .swf file, when open this .swf, it just shows the HTML file, behaves like a browser

Comment: then why do you need SWF or AIR, just open the html in browser ?

Comment: Thanks for reply:) my requirement is not **open a browser**, my swf should **be the browser** to display my HTML file, that is, with only the swf file (which contains a HTML file embedded at compile stage) I should be able to view and interact with that HTML file, even when no browser is installed on my OS.

Comment: huh... this is a strange requirement. Have you considered any other technologies for the solution: like c++/c# , java ? If you have to run flash you still have to presume flash player is installed and .swf files will automatically open with the flash player. Also another point: how complex is your html ?

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu Unfotunately, the entire thing is, I'm forced to participate a flash contest so my works must be .swf file, however I am not familiar with flash but is quite proficient in HTML/CSS/JS, thus I was thinking a way to make me write HTML and run in flash. Now since it seems quite impossible, I may try to find another solution (ask for help from flash developers e.g).

Comment: Sorry to inform, but what you are looking for may not be possible. FlashPlayer is not a browser and even if AIR is capable of running html, you will still run into big problems with css / js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed package the AIR runtime into your application, but the end product will be a native executable, not a SWF file..

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f709e16db131e43659b9-8000.html